# How to get resource in swf file?

Tags: decompilation, actionscript, swf

I use this site http://www.showmycode.com/ to decompile the swf below
http://kwcdn.000dn.com/swfs/8b/23440heisesm/bg.swf

But the code only shows the link for a video but I can not get the image in the background. Where and how is that image is embedded in the swf? How can I retrieve that image?

Long story short, I want to search which game is it, from an ads in a Chinese site, but I can not read any Chinese, and the ads is a fake lead to a fake game. So the easiest way is to decompile the swf and use the image in google search hoping for some results. The decomplied code is shown below:

```
function video_replay()
{
    my_ns.seek(0);
}
var str_url = "http://kwflvcdn.000dn.com/swfs/17/23308hssm/hesm.flv";
var my_nc = new netconnection();
my_nc.connect(null);
var my_ns = new netstream(my_nc);
my_ns.setbuffertime(0);
var my_video;
my_video.attachvideo(my_ns);
my_video.smoothing = true;
my_ns.play(str_url);
var m_iErrorCount = 0;
my_ns.onstatus = function (infoObject)
{
    if ((infoObject.level == "error") && (m_iErrorCount < 2))
    {
        m_iErrorCount++;
        var _local2 = setTimeout(video_replay, 3);
    }
    else if (infoObject.code == "NetStream.Play.Stop")
    {
        var _local2 = setTimeout(video_replay, 0);
    }
    else if (infoObject.code == "NetStream.Buffer.Flush")
    {
         trace(my_ns.time);
    }
};
```

Comment: try loading the video in chrome (install VLC Player) which will install Chrome VLC Player plugin and then you can resize to full screen video and take some high quality screenshots which you can upload to google image search for some results. The game does look nice let me know what it is when you find it.

Comment: Found the game: http://bdtg.37.com/s/1/1789/22338.html?baidu_key=395e3e9222fd2722

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EDUyzrxR-mY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EDUyzrxR-mY

game found enjoy it if you like. This is the real game from that flash teaser

The game I found myself as well while I was visiting chinese upload websites
http://bdtg.37.com/s/1/1789/22338.html?baidu_key=395e3e9222fd2722

Comment: haha, thanks. But that youtube vid is misleading, the actual game is black desert and here is the screen shot of that ads http://black-desert.com/races/

Comment: yup in comments it really did a good job fooling me as a kalonline player haha :P

Answer (score 2):

Although I do not fully understand your questions, you might try SWFtools, a set of utilities that help you deal with all kinds of swf problems

http://www.swftools.org

Another flash decompiler is:
http://www.free-decompiler.com/flash/

If you want to get the background or still image that is shown before you start the video, just browse the source of that website and search for ".swf". There should be a link to an image near/in the "flashvars" code.

Hope this helps at least a bit.

Answer (score 2):

THis is one of the canonical sources:

http://jmendeth.com/blog/reverse-engineering-flash/